# How to use silverstripe-image-click-spots?

Tags: silverstripe-4

I am trying to get https://github.com/sunnysideup/silverstripe-image-click-spots to work.

After adding some lines  (use ...) and correcting the classes (some left - outs and typos) I can't find out how to use the module.

Unfortunately, the image-click-spots.yml.example is missing on GitHub and the docs are very poor.

All I see is:

```yaml
MyDataObject:
  extensions:
    - Sunnysideup\ImageClickSpots\Extension\ImageClickSpotsExtension
```

Can you please provide a basic working example of using this module?

Comment: The module includes a README and documentation - if that documentation is not sufficient to get you started, please raise an issue in GitHub for that module.
Similarly, if there are bugs (you mentioned you had to add some use statements for example?) please raise issues in GitHub about those.